# Auto check checkboxes based on select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have working code to check checkboxes **but it only works if the first checkbox is already checked.** Do you guys maybe have any idea why?

**HTML**:

```
<p id="ullman_seats"><input class="choice" type="checkbox" name="option['option']" value="3000"> Ullman seats
    <select id="select_ullman">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
</p>
<p id="ullman_seats_2"><input class="choice" type="checkbox" name="option['option']" value="3000"> Ullman seats</p>
<p id="ullman_seats_3"><input class="choice" type="checkbox" name="option['option']" value="3000"> Ullman seats</p>
<p id="ullman_seats_4"><input class="choice" type="checkbox" name="option['option']" value="3000"> Ullman seats</p>
```

**jQuery** (safe because it will be implemented in WordPress)

```
jQuery('#select_ullman').change(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == '2') {
            jQuery('#ullman_seats input').attr('checked', true);
            jQuery('#ullman_seats_2 input').attr('checked', true);
        }if (jQuery(this).val() == '3') {
            jQuery('#ullman_seats input').attr('checked', true);
            jQuery('#ullman_seats_2 input').attr('checked', true);
            jQuery('#ullman_seats_3 input').attr('checked', true);
        }if (jQuery(this).val() == '4') {
            jQuery('#ullman_seats input').attr('checked', true);
            jQuery('#ullman_seats_2 input').attr('checked', true);
            jQuery('#ullman_seats_3 input').attr('checked', true);
            jQuery('#ullman_seats_4 input').attr('checked', true);
        }
   }
```

Comment: @Tushar No it's really that first issue, the latter I can fix :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong method, you could change `.attr('checked', true)` to `.prop('checked', true)` etc. to make it work, but there's a much easier way to do this

```
jQuery('#select_ullman').on('change', function() {
    $('.ullman_seats input').prop('checked', function(i, prop) {
        return i < this.value;
    }.bind(this));
}).trigger('change');
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/69uwa3ve/2/)

Use the callback for `prop()` and compare the index of each element directly

Comment: You can also use the `:gt` selector to uncheck the checkbox instead of unchecking all the checkboxes first and then checking first `n` checkbox, uncheck the checkboxes other than first `n` i.e. `n+1` and then check first `n` checkboxes.

Comment: @Tushar - how about that, just checking the index in the callback, seems easier.

Comment: Thanks! The code works great in the fiddle but for some reason it doesn't in my local code. I tracked the issue to `jQuery(".choice:checked").each(function() {
            total += parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
  });
        
  if (total == 0) {
   jQuery('#amount').val('');
  } else {
            total = total + addition;
   jQuery('#amount').val(total);
  }` do you maybe have any idea what's causing this?

Comment: @RaimondvanMouche If the events are not bound, you want to wrap the code in `ready`(_if not already wrapped_)

Comment: @adeneo That's just great!

Comment: @RaimondvanMouche - The code you posted in the comment seems fine, all though not related to the question, so it's hard to know where it's used. Try `document.ready` as Tushar suggests and see if that solves it.

Comment: @Tushar yes I had wrapped it in ready (actually document.ready) so that unfortunately isn't the issue. If it helps, I uploaded all the JS (it's not much, but not optimised either) [here](http://dev.lexerim.nl/boats/js/scripts.js)

Comment: @RaimondvanMouche Can you debug step by step 1. Is event bound 2. Getting selected value 3. Getting checkboxes by selectors ...

Comment: @Tushar I found the bug. I simply was reading the code wrong and it did fell outside the scope of the `ready`. Sorry for wasting your time! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You must use .prop('checked', true);

```
jQuery('#select_ullman').change(function () {
        if (jQuery(this).val() == '2') {
            jQuery('#ullman_seats input').prop('checked', true);
            jQuery('#ullman_seats_2 input').prop('checked', true);
        }if (jQuery(this).val() == '3') {
            jQuery('#ullman_seats input').prop('checked', true);
            jQuery('#ullman_seats_2 input').prop('checked', true);
            jQuery('#ullman_seats_3 input').prop('checked', true);
        }if (jQuery(this).val() == '4') {
            jQuery('#ullman_seats input').prop('checked', true);
            jQuery('#ullman_seats_2 input').prop('checked', true);
            jQuery('#ullman_seats_3 input').prop('checked', true);
            jQuery('#ullman_seats_4 input').prop('checked', true);
        }    }
```

and for check checkbox is checked

```
if ($('#id').is(':checked') == true) {
            //Do something
        }
        else {
            //Do something else
        }
```